# Checkboxes and forms in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, model-view-controller, checkbox

I have a controller that loads data from a database and shows that in the form of table.
There I have a buttons at the top to perform bulk actions.
And checkbox in front of each row in table to perform bulk action.
Now i want to connect these checkboxes with above buttons. How can i do this?
This is my view code?Or any other way to connect checkboxes and buttons?

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Controllers.Table>
@{
   Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ETL</title>
    <link href="~/Content/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.onload = function () {
                            alert("@ViewBag.Message");
                             };
        </script>
    }

</head>

<body>
    <div class="containers">
        <table class="containers" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="243"><h3 style="padding-bottom:10px;">ETL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</h3></td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "ETL", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <td width="140">
                            <select class="form-control" style="width:160px; "name="select" id="select">
                                <option name="status">Status</option>
                                <option name="job id">Job Id</option>
                                <option name="Application">Application</option>
                                <option name="Package">Package</option>
                                <option name="Schedulepriority">Schedule Priority</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td width="163"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"></td>
                        <td width="323"><input class="form-control" style="width:100px; " type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                    }
                    **<form>
                        <td width="41"><input class="Hold btn" type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Hold"></td>
                        <td width="70"><input class="Complete btn" type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Complete"></td>
                        <td width="61"><input class="Pending btn" type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="Pending"></td>
                        <td width="54"><input class="Cancel btn" type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="Cancel"></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>**
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="containers">
        <table class="containers table table-bordered" border="1">
            <thead>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Job ID</th>
            <th>Application name</th>
            <th>Schedule Name</th>
            <th>Schedule Priority</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>Last Run Time</th>
            <th width="89">Time Since Last Failed</th>
            <th width="101">Actions</th></thead>
            <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
                <tr>
                    @{var aff=item.id+"";
                    }
                    <td width="40"><input type="checkbox" name=@aff id=@aff class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td width="84">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
                    <td width="148">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.appname)</td>
                    <td width="150">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scdname)</td>


                    <td width="113">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)</td>
                    <td width="118">@if (item.status.ToLower().Contains("fail"))
                    {
                        using (Html.BeginForm("Data", "ETL", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="@item.id" />
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Failed" class="Cancel btn"/>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
                    }</td>
                    <td width="152">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pname)</td>
                    <td width="78">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lasttime)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.status.Equals("Cancelled") || item.status.Equals("Pending") || item.status.Equals("Failed"))
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("H","Update", routeValues: new { id = item.id,method="hold"}, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Hold btn" });
                        }
@if (item.status.Equals("Hold") || item.status.Equals("Failed"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "C", actionName: "Update", routeValues: new { id = item.id, method = "completed" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Complete btn"});
}
@if (item.status.Equals("Cancelled") || item.status.Equals("Completed") || item.status.Equals("Failed") || item.status.Equals("Hold"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "P", actionName: "Update", routeValues: new { id = item.id, method = "pending" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Pending btn "});
}
@if ( item.status.Equals("Launched"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "C", actionName: "Update", routeValues: new { id = item.id, method = "cancel" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Cancel btn" });
}
                    </td>
                </tr>
}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Form code:

```
<form>
                            <td width="41"><input class="Hold btn" type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Hold"></td>
                            <td width="70"><input class="Complete btn" type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Complete"></td>
                            <td width="61"><input class="Pending btn" type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="Pending"></td>
                            <td width="54"><input class="Cancel btn" type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="Cancel"></td>
                        </form>
```

And these are checkboxes, i am generating dynamically.

```
<tr>
                        @{var aff=item.id+"";
                        }
                        <td width="40"><input type="checkbox" name=@aff id=@aff class="form-control"/></td>
```

[In this image there are four buttons at top and checkboxes in front of each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu2E1.png)

Comment: you want to do this on postback (in C# controller), or in Javascript? Either way you need to find all the checkboxes which are checked and then use that list somehow. You haven't made clear what the buttons will actually do in your case - do they do something else on the page, or submit data to an API, or redirect to another page? The exact use case can influence the exact way you solve the problem.

Comment: They will just be redirecting to C# controller. And doing some updates to those rows which are checked.

Comment: Use gridview asp.net control will be better